# is there a way to find the value in the cell before it was changed using javascript

Tags: javascript

is there a way to find out the value in the cell before and after it is changed in javascript or jQuery? I am thinking I might have to use combination of events like onfocus and onblur. please let me know.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse it is possible. Method I prefer to store temporary data is to store them inside object/variable. I am just not sure if you refer to table cell or database cell, but essentially it makes no difference. Using focus it would go like this:

```
var $temp_before;
var $temp_after;
$('#cell_id').focus(function(){
  $temp_before = this.html(); // or this.text() depending on what you want to record
  /*... call to function to change it ...*/
  $temp_after = this.html();
});
```

As comment from [Cory Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74757/cory-larson) suggests, you can also store data inside the element itself using [jQuery data](http://docs.jquery.com/Data).

```
$('#cell_id').focus(function(){
  this.data("old_content", this.html());
  /*... call to function to change it ...*/
  this.data("new_content", this.html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to write the old value to a hidden field on the page and then have access to both the current value from the edited field, and the old value from the hidden field.

Comment: You wouldn't even need a hidden field -- write the old value as an attribute on the element itself.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I am trying to find if there are any other ways to do this.